# Cannot resolve certain symbols in android studio

Tags: java, android, class

I've been having this error where this class(DataProvider) for my project that I just created will not seem to accept .add or .put.  But my MainActivity class accepts them just fine.  I’ve already done the Invalidate Caches and Restart.  Can someone explain to me why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?

DataProvider:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class DataProvider {
public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getInfo()

HashMap<String, List<String>> MoviesDetails = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

List<String> Action_Movies = new ArrayList<String>();
 //'.add'  would be an error in red.  Cannot resolve symbol 'add'. 
Action_Movies.add("");
List<String> Romantic_Movies = new ArrayList<String>();

Romantic_Movies.add("");
List<String> Horror_Movies = new ArrayList<String>();
Horror_Movies.add("");
List<String> Comedy_Movies = new ArrayList<String>();
Comedy_Movies.add("");
```

}

MainActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
HashMap<String, List<String>> Movies_categories;
List<String> Movies_list;
ExpandableListView Exp_list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    List<String> Test = new ArrayList<String>();
    Test.add("Test");



}
```

}

Comment: The DataProvider class won't compile since getInfo() method does not have braces. Fix this error and try compiling again.

Comment: As a side note: Try to stick to Java / Android naming conventions. Variables / fields are camelCased and always start with a lower case letter (romanticMovies).

Comment: As a side note, it's common practice to not start variable names with a capital letter. Consider using camel-back notation. Ex: `List<String> actionMovies;`

Comment: Darn, jan, you beat me to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon at the end of this line:

```
public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getInfo()
```

Which makes the code analysed go crazy and not see your objects correctly as their types. Just add the semicolon.

Also, you will probably want to remove the parenthesis at the end of the line, as it suggests it it a method. So do something like this:

```
public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getInfo;
```

Or this:

```
public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getInfo(){
    //Some actual code here, which returns a HashMap
};
```

Now I see that your whole class tructure is messed up. Try the below code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class DataProvider {
public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getInfo;

    public DataProvider() { 

        HashMap<String, List<String>> MoviesDetails = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        List<String> Action_Movies = new ArrayList<String>();
        Action_Movies.add("");
        List<String> Romantic_Movies = new ArrayList<String>();

        Romantic_Movies.add("");
        List<String> Horror_Movies = new ArrayList<String>();
        Horror_Movies.add("");
        List<String> Comedy_Movies = new ArrayList<String>();
        Comedy_Movies.add("");

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that.  It just makes an error for some reason. I get this error: 'Missing method body, or declare abstract'.  It also still doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Did you try examples 2 and 3 as well?

Comment: Yes, I tried both.  Still getting the same error regarding the .add cannot be resolved

Comment: Here, I pasted code which will compile. The problem was that most of your code was outside a method! In Java, all functional code should be enclosed in a method. I put the code you provided into the constructor of your DataProvider method, but I am not sure what it was supposed to do, so you will have to reformat it.

Answer (score 2):

On another side note, consider creating your variables outside of the constructor and initializing them inside the constructor.

```
public class DataProvider {
    public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getInfo;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> movieDetails;
    List<String> actionMovies;
    List<String> romanticMovies;
    List<String> horrorMovies;
    List<String> comedyMovies;

    public DataProvider() {
        movieDetails = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        actionMovies = new ArrayList<String>();
        actionMovies.add("");
        romanticMovies = new ArrayList<String>();
        romanticMovies.add("");
        horrorMovies = new ArrayList<String>();
        horrorMovies.add("");
        comedyMovies = new ArrayList<String>();
        comedyMovies.add("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really related with the topic, but a good point. You have my upvote sir :-)

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind.  It looks a better than what I coded. Nice contribution.

Answer (score 0):

These lines may have been added inside the class but outside the constructor or method. **Make sure the instructions are within a method**.